# python BeautifulSoup finding certain things in a table

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Folks,
  Ive managed to get beautifulsoup to scrape a page with the following

```
html =  response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.findAll('a')
```

There are several occurrences of

```
<A href="javascript:Set_Variables('foo1','bar1''')"onmouseover="javascript: return window.status=''">
<A href="javascript:Set_Variables('foo2','bar2''')"onmouseover="javascript: return window.status=''">
```

How can I iterate through this and get the foo/bar values?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to extract variables from `href` attributes:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <table>
        <A href="javascript:Set_Variables('foo1','bar1''')" onmouseover="javascript: return window.status=''">
        <A href="javascript:Set_Variables('foo2','bar2''')" onmouseover="javascript: return window.status=''">
    </table>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

pattern = re.compile(r"javascript:Set_Variables\('(\w+)','(\w+)'")
for a in soup('a'):
    match = pattern.search(a['href'])
    if match:
        print match.groups()
```

Prints:

```
('foo1', 'bar1')
('foo2', 'bar2')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: Im going to update my question.  I mislead you.  i am not finding any tables on the page :(